# run php script inside javascript without leaving page

Tags: php, javascript

I have a javascript alert (from an image onclick) - I want to have an alert box and run a php script. Right now I have this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function doit() {
 window.location.href='script.php';
 alert("test");
 }
</script>
```

It works, except that it physically takes me to the script page. I want to just run the php script and stay on the current page I'm on.

any ideas? Also, I was using AJAX but had serious issues with it working in IE and iOS so I decided to not use it.

Comment: AJAX is the answer. If you continue to struggle, consider using a framework such as jQuery or Prototype, since they handle a lot of the cross-browser issues for you. If you encounter specific issues as you implement your solution, feel free to post the relevant details on StackOverflow for assistance.

Comment: You have to use ajax. [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) will help you solving the cross-compatibility issues.

Comment: AJAX is the way to go. If you use a library such as jQuery, then x-browser issues are much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Use AJAX provider such as `jQuery`.

Have a look at [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

With AJAX, you can execute PHP scripts without leaving the current page.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to use AJAX. It is EXACTLY for the kind of situation you have just described. Cross compatibility issues can be minimized with use of jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function doit() {
 $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'script.php',
    success:function(res){
     alert("test");
   }
  });
 }
</script>
```